# Is There A Way to DRY Up These Vue Attributes?

Tags: vuejs2

```
<designs-dialog
      @change="dialogHandler"
      @close="dialogs.designs = false"
      :dialog="dialogs.designs"
      :job="dialogJob"
      v-if="dialogs.designs"
    />
    <details-dialog
      @change="dialogHandler"
      @close="dialogs.details = false"
      :dialog="dialogs.details"
      :job="dialogJob"
      v-if="dialogs.details"
    />
```

These 2 components are different in that one is more of a table and the other is more of a carousel. Nevertheless, it seems that there should be some way to DRY up the attributes as that part seems very similar between the 2.

Comment: This might be too broad of a question. You could make a general dialog component that shares some of the common logic. You could also use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) and specify the props to pass with a computed property. It sorta depends on the rest of the structure of your app.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`v-bind` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to bind an object of attributes?

Comment: @thanksd Never saw dynamic components. Will explore that. Tx.

Comment: I got it refactored satisfactorily using `<component v-bind:is` 